# How to test try catch code in javascript using jest and including a next() call with middleware in express?

Tags: node.js, express, unit-testing, try-catch, sinon

I am creating an API and I want to know how to test a try catch block. I want to make sure that error catch by the block is passing throw next() in express to the next middleware.

Here an example, this is my callback to POST method:

```
function create (req, res, next) {
  try {
    const data = {}
    response(req, res, data, 201)
  } catch (error) {
    next(error)
  }
}
```

I want to test that next is called. I am planing to use **sinon** to do it, but I want to simulate the error and verify that catching the error.

This is an screen of my coverage in jest.

[image]

Comment: Stub the `response` function and make it throw an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it were too much effort to reproduce an actual error, I'd just not cover that statement.

Thanks to Jest's mock functions it's possible to *spy on* functions, methods and modules and temporarily replace it's implementation and return value.

**https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api**

That would be something like

```
// replace the implementation for your stub
const spy = jest.spyOn(response).mockImplementation(() => { throw new Error(); });
...
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
spy.mockRestore(); // restore the implementation
```

Mind you this syntax work for functions. If it this a method from a class, then it would be `jest.spyOn(YourClass.prototype, 'methodNameInsideQuotes')`. Jest is well-documented and you should get it working with no hacks.